# Best book to understand representation theory.

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, book-recommendation, characters, group-rings

I have tried to read representation and character theory from a few books but none of them was working for me, like Lieback and Serre. I want to understand representation and character to use them and understand their application in group rings. In many group rings texts and research papers character theory is highly used and much too advanced for me to understand yet. Can somebody suggest a a book which can help me get a feel of both representations and characters so that there association with group rings becomes more clear and I can get comfortable confronting them in any of the proofs.

My main concern is representations and character theory being used in some parts and proofs of group rings. I wont need anything advanced in the field if it is not use in the area of group rings. Although they do almost include all parts of algebra.

Comment: Have you tried Chapter VI of Dummit and Foote?

Comment: It looks good. I will read it.Thanks